# How can I refresh cefsettings while running my app?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am trying to change cefsettings whilst my app is running, I want this so I can change the user-agent while it's running.

I have tried to run Cef.Shutdown(); and initialize it again, which I learned isn't allowed in Cefsharp, I've also tried to find a way to find and change the settings possibly using a variable located in Cef.___

Is there anyway to refresh my CefSettings while my program is running? Or change the variables individually, instead of changing which instance of CefSettings is being used? It was hard to find the same question online for me, possibly because I didn't know what keywords to search.

Thanks.

Comment: You can change the user agent at runtime see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#useragent You cannot modify CefSettings directly.

Comment: Works almost perfect with a few bugs, but it's good enough! Thanks, you should've put this as an answer!

Comment: Link only answers aren't allowed and I didn't have time to write  a detailed answer.